# How to use array of data from different Views - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have application that has 2 Views. One just keeps an empty array and shows it, and the other one view should add data in this array. In the end I want added info to show on the view that keeps this array.

I've already tried to create an variable of another view inside of the first one, and try to change array, but as i experienced, it doesn't work, because it just created a new instance of view, that has nothing in common with the one that I want to update.

`

```
//View that keeps array "savedArticles"

struct SavedNewsView: View {
    @State var savedArticles: [Article] = []
    
    func removeArticle(at offsets:IndexSet) {
        savedArticles.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(savedArticles, id: \.self) {article in
                    NewsComponentView(title: article.title, description: article.description, urlToImage: article.urlToImage, url: article.url)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeArticle)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Saved News")
    }
}
```

`

And this is the view that updates this array:

`

```
struct NewsView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var savedArray = SavedNewsView()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.news, id: \.self) {article in
                if article.urlToImage != nil {
                    NewsComponentView(title: article.title, description: article.description, urlToImage: article.urlToImage, url: article.url)
                        .swipeActions() {
                            Button {
                                savedArray.savedArticles.append(Article(title: article.title, description: article.description, url: article.url, urlToImage: article.urlToImage))
                            } label: {
                                Label("Save", systemImage: "bookmark")
                            }
                            .tint(.yellow)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetch()
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: You don’t use an instance of a view to pass data but instead a class conforming to  ObservableObject that you use as a StateObject/ObservedObject or EnvironmentObject depending on your exact use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass write access to an `@State` to a subview using `@Binding`, e.g.

```
struct NewsView: View {
    @Binding var savedArticles: [Article]
```

`NewsView(savedArticles: $savedArticles)`